# view page in cakephp not working,undefined index

Tags: cakephp

i cannot find out what is wrong with my code.the view page doesn't display.

my controller:

```
public function Modules_View( $id = Null)
        {

        $module = $this->Module->findByid($id);
        $this->set('module',$module);

        }
```

in my .ctp file

```
<?php echo $module['Module']['moduleName']; ?>
```

its throwing error in the above line.saying undefined index

i am using PostgreSQL for database

Comment: do pr($module); in your function to check if you're getting the data ..!

Comment: yes my database is storing the data.

Comment: can you show sample output when you do pr($module);...?

Comment: Array
(
) its an empty array

Comment: so thats the reason you are getting "undefined index" error, as you dont have any data for $this->Module->findByid($id);

Comment: yes u r right for id=1 there is no data.i have created the primary key serial .so for some reason its generating random numbers,how do i fix this

Comment: you need to make auto_increment key for id so that database handles it on its own

Answer (score 1):

you need to check if you have data or not prior to `echo()`'ing it, like change:

```
$module = $this->Module->findByid($id);
```

to

```
$module = $this->Module->findById($id); //it should be Id not id
```

and in view `.ctp` file , do a check before trying to output data, like

```
if( !empty($module) AND !empty($module["Module"]) ) {
   echo $module['Module']['moduleName'];
}
else {
    //show some message as there's no data for related id
}
```